# Displaying posts from a selected category only

Tags: php, wordpress

How to display (by modifying a theme) posts from a certain category only instead of showing them all?

Comment: by eating a monkey.... can you show code to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its simplest form:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=foo' );
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <!-- post's contents -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers you seek lie in the Wordpress documentation. It's there if you look for more than 2 seconds: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Loop_Examples